# Python: logging.streamhandler is not sending logs to stdout

Tags: python, logging

I want to use StreamHandler logging handler of python.
What i have tried is,

```
import logging
import sys
mylogger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
h1 = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
h1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

mylogger.addHandler(h1)

# now trying to log with the created logger
mylogger.debug("abcd") # <no output>
mylogger.info("abcd") # <no output>
mylogger.warn("abcd") # abcd
```

Am i missing something ? Or doing any wrong ?
Why INFO and DEBUG level logs are not coming on STDOUT ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have to set the level of the logger, not only the level of the handler:

```
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Here is a nice graphic of the logging workflow, where you can see that either the logger and the handler check for the log level:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow

The default `logLevel` is `WARNING`, so even if you set the level of your handler to `DEBUG`, the message will not get through, since your logger suppresses it (it's also by default `WARNING`).

By the way, you can do some basic formatting with `Formatter`:

```
import logging
import sys

mylogger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")

formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')

handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

mylogger.addHandler(handler)
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

mylogger.debug("This is a debug message.")
mylogger.info("Some info message.")
mylogger.warning("A warning.")
```

Will give you the output

```
[DEBUG] This is a debug message.
[INFO] Some info message.
[WARNING] A warning.
```

Comment: I was following some basic documents, http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial Doc says setLevel on handler. Is this document wrong ?

Comment: No it's not wrong, as you can see in http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow the logger passes the logging call to its handler after it checks the level. So if the level of the logger is set to `WARN`, and a `DEBUG` message is arriving, nothing gets through. If a message passes, the logger hands it out to the handler, which also has a logging type "filter".